# Activity Recognition in Android is not working

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-recognition

I have tried to compile example code from new Google location API that should show user's activity. Like on foot, in vehicle etc.

Link to the example is
http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

In my case what I can see is that Google Play Services is available, Location Services connection goes fine as well but nothing afterwards. 
**onHandleIntent** never been called obviously.

Have somebody tried to make it work? 
Or are there some other working examples available on the Internet?

Thanks

Comment: Which device are you testing on? Can you verify that settings->location-access->WiFi & mobile network location is enabled?

Comment: Similar to my case. I've just forgot to register IntentService in manifest :)

Answer (score 5):

Is there any chance you forgot to add your service to the manifest?
Something like

```
<application>
    ......
    <service
        android:name="your.package.ActivityRecognitionIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: added, still not being called